# Office Excel AddIn Custom Function with Angular template

Tags: angular, excel, office-js, excel-addins

I am trying Office Excel Addin, I am able to create the excel addin with `yo office`.

But, the built-in template `angular template for taskpane` and `custom function` is split, I want to create a project which will have custom function and taskpane angular.

I tried to merge the two template into one, but excel message bar keeps `xx is working on your Show Taskpane`, and did not show the taskpane.

Here is a test project.

https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/Meekou.Excel

Answer (score -2):

Yes, unfortunately, we don't have a sample project or guidance for creating a custom function add-in using Angular.

Here is some advice. Besides adding your functions.js and functions.html file, you also have to change some config in the manifest.xml file and webpack.config.js file to make your custom functions work.

Through comparing the task pane add-in sample project and custom function sample project. You can learn how to change the config in the manifest.xml file and webpack.config.js file.

Sorry for the trouble caused by missing guidance. If it doesn't work, please contact me then.

Comment: What do you mean by `change some config`? Can you point out detail steps instead of common suggestion? I already tried to merge angular template and excel custom function template to one, but hit issues.